# $L^1$ convergence of product of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, martingales

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of non-negative, integrable, independent random variables such that $\forall n, E(X_n)=1$. Let $Y_0=1$ and $Y_n=\prod_{k=1}^n X_k$. Suppose that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty E(\sqrt {X_k})>0$ (the limit of the product exists and is positive). Prove that $Y_n$ converges with respect to the $L^1$ norm.

It's easily seen that $Y_n$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F_n =\sigma(X_0,\ldots X_n)$. Then $\sqrt{Y_n}$ is a positive supermartingale, hence converges almost surely to some $Z$. Thus $Y_n$ converges almost surely to $Z^2$. I haven't been able to prove that $Y_n$ converges in $L^1$ to $Z^2$... I don't see how I can take advantage of the assumption $\prod_{k=1}^\infty E(\sqrt {X_k})>0$.

Comment: Are you sure about the assumption on the product? (It seems to me that it implies $X_n=1$ almost surely... but perhaps I'm missing something and/or there is a mistake in my computations.)

Comment: @saz silly typo of mine ! The correct assumption is $\prod_{k=1}^\infty E(\sqrt {X_k})>0$ (sorry for wasting your time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $a_n:=E(\sqrt{X_n})$ and
$$M_n:=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{X_k}}{a_k}.$$
Then $\{M_n\}$ is a non-negative martingale with respect to $\{\mathcal F_n\}$. Moreover, we have
$$E(M_n^2)=E\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{X_k}{a_k^2}\right)=\frac{E(Y_n)}{\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2}\le\frac1{\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k\right)^2}<\infty,$$
where the inequality follows since $E(Y_n)=1$ and $a_k\le1$ by Jensen's inequality. Thus by the $L^2$-martingale convergence theorem, $M_n\to M_\infty$ almost surely and in $L^2$. Since $Y_n=\left(\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right)^2M_n^2$, it follows that $\{Y_n\}$ is uniformly integrable and thus $Y_n\to Z$ in $L^1$.

Note: the converse holds. That is, if $\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k=0$, then $Y_n\to0$ almost surely. Together these two results are called Kakutani's theorem.

Comment: Despite the fact that Kakutani's paper makes no mention of martingales....

Comment: @JohnDawkins I believe the theory of martingales was in its infancy when Kakutani first came up with his result, but that perhaps he later revisited it in the context of martingales?

Comment: Kakutani's "dichotomy" concerned the  absolute continuity or singularity of products of probability measures. It was later realized that the martingale convergence theorem was a perfect tool for proving the theorem. I'm not sure where the first such martingale treatment of K's theorem occurs.

Comment: @Jason: Why does the last inequality $\frac1{\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k\right)^2}<\infty$ hold?

Comment: @Quasar By assumption, $\prod_{k=1}^\infty a_k>0$.

Comment: @Jason: Couldn't it be that it converges to 0. E.g. if $a_k=1/i$ the product would converge to 0. How can we know that this is not the case here?

Comment: EDIT: I meant $a_k=1/k$.

Comment: @Quasar By assumption! "Suppose that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty E(\sqrt{X_k})>0$" was written in the problem statement, and I set $a_k=E(\sqrt{X_k})$.

Comment: @Jason: Yes of course! Sorry for the stupid question.